PPTP Client VPN problem
I have a provider to provide me with a PPTP VPN profile. In my Windows, I am having no problem connecting this pptp vpn.
As I am new to Ubuntu I tried almost all solutions but nothing worked. Please help me on this. Here is the log I find when use
Sep 10 02:51:30 Sp3cTer-Desktop NetworkManager[43384]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.9/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Sep 10 02:51:30 Sp3cTer-Desktop pptp[43389]: nm-pptp-service-43380 log[main:pptp.c:353]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Sep 10 02:51:30 Sp3cTer-Desktop pptp[43397]: nm-pptp-service-43380 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:258]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
Sep 10 02:51:30 Sp3cTer-Desktop pptp[43397]: nm-pptp-service-43380 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:781]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
Sep 10 02:51:30 Sp3cTer-Desktop pptp[43397]: nm-pptp-service-43380 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:815]: Client connection established.
Sep 10 02:51:31 Sp3cTer-Desktop pptp[43397]: nm-pptp-service-43380 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:258]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
Sep 10 02:51:31 Sp3cTer-Desktop pptp[43397]: nm-pptp-service-43380 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:900]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
Sep 10 02:51:31 Sp3cTer-Desktop pptp[43397]: nm-pptp-service-43380 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:938]: Outgoing call established (call ID 21329, peer's call ID 55968).
Sep 10 02:52:31 Sp3cTer-Desktop pptp[43397]: nm-pptp-service-43380 log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:719]: Echo Reply received.
Sep 10 02:53:16 Sp3cTer-Desktop pptp[43389]: nm-pptp-service-43380 warn[pqueue_add:pqueue.c:151]: discarding duplicate packet 2239
Sep 10 02:53:16 Sp3cTer-Desktop pptp[43389]: nm-pptp-service-43380 warn[pqueue_add:pqueue.c:151]: discarding duplicate packet 2239
Sep 10 02:53:16 Sp3cTer-Desktop pptp[43389]: nm-pptp-service-43380 warn[pqueue_add:pqueue.c:151]: discarding duplicate packet 2240
Sep 10 02:53:16 Sp3cTer-Desktop pptp[43389]: nm-pptp-service-43380 warn[pqueue_add:pqueue.c:151]: discarding duplicate packet 2246
Sep 10 02:53:31 Sp3cTer-Desktop pptp[43397]: nm-pptp-service-43380 log[logecho:pptp_ctrl.c:719]: Echo Reply received.
Sep 10 02:54:09 Sp3cTer-Desktop pptp[43397]: nm-pptp-service-43380 log[pptp_read_some:pptp_ctrl.c:586]: read returned zero, peer has closed
Sep 10 02:54:09 Sp3cTer-Desktop pptp[43397]: nm-pptp-service-43380 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:269]: Closing connection (shutdown)
Sep 10 02:54:09 Sp3cTer-Desktop pptp[43397]: nm-pptp-service-43380 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:258]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Sep 10 02:54:09 Sp3cTer-Desktop pptp[43397]: nm-pptp-service-43380 log[pptp_read_some:pptp_ctrl.c:586]: read returned zero, peer has closed
Sep 10 02:54:09 Sp3cTer-Desktop pptp[43397]: nm-pptp-service-43380 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:84]: Closing connection (call state)

Please help. It freaks me out.
I have added those lines in /etc/ufw/before.rules
# rules.before

# gre
-A ufw-before-input -p 47 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -p 47 -j ACCEPT

On provider end there is no problem.

Contact the VPN provider and ask them is where I would start.

Their end has no problem.

Would be good to add that to the question.
